# Override base Gutenberg block default spacing in child theme's theme.json

Tags: block-editor, embed, theme.json

I am trying to change the default top spacing (margin) for the `Embed` block used in Gutenberg. I noticed that for some reason, the default setting is

```
.wp-block-embed {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

which resets the top margin and removes the space between the preceding component.

My site is currently running a child block theme. I decided to apply global style override by adding the following to `theme.json`:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/wp/6.4/theme.json",
    "styles": {
        "blocks": {
            "core/embed": {
                "spacing": {
                    "margin": {
                        "top": "2rem"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this in fact adds the new top margin to the CSS, however it's earlier in the CSS compared to the original one, thus the override does not work:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

I checked the location of that base `0 0 1em` style and it is in:

```
/wp-includes/blocks/embed/theme.css
```

Is there a smart way to override that spacing?
I'd prefer to avoid overriding in theme's `style.css` as this seems wrong since `theme.json` has appeared.

It is probably worth mentioning that I am aware that I can change the spacing through Gutenberg Editor, however I want to apply the default, globally, when it comes to spacing.

Comment: It seems wrong that the theme.json change you made gets output earlier than the default. It may be worth checking if it’s a reported bug and reporting it if not. It seems ideally the change would replace the default not have both output. ‍♂️

Comment: I could not find anything that would related to my issue. Created a bug, if anyone is interested: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/59934.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Global Styles Filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/global-styles-filters/) to override the style:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_theme_json_data_default', function ( $theme_json ){
    $new_data = array(
        'version'  => 2,
        'styles' => [
            'blocks' => [
                'core/embed' => [
                    'spacing' => [
                        'margin' => [
                            'top' => '2rem'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    return $theme_json->update_with( $new_data );
});
```

An alternative that may also work is using the Global Styles UI in the (Site) Editor to change the default style of the block. Yet I think that’s not a viable option if you want your override to be part of a version-controlled theme.

Comment: I was not aware of this filter, thank you. But this also seems like a workaround...